# Save entity in Grails custom event listener

Tags: grails

I'm writing Grails 2.3.7 application and I have 2 domain entities there: `Comment` and `Event`. Each new `Comment` saved in database should generate and persist corresponding `Event`. For this I tried ti intercept `PostInsertEvent` in `AbstractPersistenceEventListener`:

```
class MyPersistenceEventListener extends AbstractPersistenceEventListener {

    public MyPersistenceEventListener(Datastore ds) {
        super(ds)
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPersistenceEvent(AbstractPersistenceEvent event) {
        Event.withTransaction {
            new Event(text: "New comment posted").save()
        }
    }

    @Override
    boolean supportsEventType(Class<? extends ApplicationEvent> eventType) {
        return eventType.isAssignableFrom(PostInsertEvent)
    }
}
```

This approach doesn't work: `onPersistenceEvent` is called, but new Event record doesn't appear in database. Is it possible to save another entity in perstence event listener or is there a better aproach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to save it in different thread:

```
class MyPersistenceEventListener extends AbstractPersistenceEventListener {

    final def eventQueue = new DataflowQueue()

    public MyPersistenceEventListener(Datastore ds) {
        super(ds)
        Dataflow.operator(inputs: [eventQueue], maxForks: 10) { event ->
            Event.withTransaction {
                event.save()
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPersistenceEvent(AbstractPersistenceEvent event) {
        if (event.entityObject instanceof Comment) {
            eventQueue << new Event(text: "New comment posted")
        }
    }

    @Override
    boolean supportsEventType(Class<? extends ApplicationEvent> eventType) {
        return eventType.isAssignableFrom(PostInsertEvent)
    }
}
```

But I'm still wonder if it is the correct solution...